# How to fork/pipe stdin in bash script?

Tags: bash, pipe, stdin

I have a script that I would like to run as

```
$ myscript < mydata.dat
```

Inside `myscript` I need to fork/pipe STDIN to multiple destinations

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

php script1.php > out1
php script2.php > out2
php script3.php > out3
```

Each one needs a copy of STDIN. Is it possible?

Something like

```
# obviously this is broken ...
STDIN | php script1.php > out1
STDIN | php script2.php > out2
STDIN | php script3.php > out3
```

Comment: I've heard that https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ is one way to do this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To copy stdin to several process, use `tee` and *process substitution*:

```
tee >(script1 > out1) >(script2 >out2) ... | lastscript >outlast
```

The construct `>(...)` is called *process substitution*.  It creates a file-like object that `tee` can write.  The command inside the parens is executed and whatever `tee` writes to it is provides to the command as stdin.

*Process substitution* is supported by bash, ksh, and zsh.  It is not POSIX and will not work under dash.

#### Simple example

Let's consider this simple script:

```
$ cat myscript 
#!/bin/bash
tee >(grep 1 >out1) >(grep 2 >out2) | grep 3 >out3
```

We can run it and verify the results:

```
$ seq 10 | bash myscript
$ cat out1
1
10
$ cat out2
2
$ cat out3
3
```

Comment: You don't need multiple `tee` commands. You can give multiple `>(...)` arguments to a single command.

Comment: Can you explain `>(...)` a little more? I've never seen that.

Comment: @naomik I added some explanation of that in the last update.  You may need to refresh your browser to see it.  Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

A variation on John1024's answer is to use named pipes in place of process substitution.

```
mkfifo p1 p2 p3
tee p1 p2 p3 > /dev/null & # or tee p1 p2 > p3 &
php script1 < p1 > out1 &
php script2 < p2 > out2 &
php script2 < p3 > out3 &
wait
rm p1 p2 p3
```

(Process substitution is effectively, and in some implementations literally, syntactic support for creating, managing, and cleaning up explicit named pipes.)

Comment: very cool to see the non-shortcut version. I highly appreciate it.

Comment: @chepner, the issue with it is that they are created in the file system and a subject for file name collisions with other processes as well as permission failures. probably, we should use tmp files to make the solution more robust.